# Finding the smallest number in a .dat file containing multiple data types | Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

**Context:** I have written a program that asks the user to enter the name and score (integer) for a user-defined quantity of players. The program then formats, slices and stores the values in a file named golf.dat

**Issue:** I am trying to expand my program to allow it to identify the player with the lowest score and print the name and score of the lowest scorer.

**My code:**

```
def playerDataInput(playerQuantity):
    outputFile = open("golf.dat", "w")
    for currentPlayer in range (1, playerQuantity + 1):
        playerName = (input("Please enter player " + format(currentPlayer, "d",)+"'s name: "))
        playerScore = (input("Please enter player " + format(currentPlayer, "d",)+"'s score: "))
        outputFile.write(playerName + "\n")
        outputFile.write(str(playerScore) + "\n")
    outputFile.close()

def playerDataOutput():
    inputFile = open("golf.dat", "r")
    playerName = inputFile.readline()
    while playerName != "":
        playerScore = inputFile.readline()
        playerName = playerName.rstrip("\n")
        playerScore = playerScore.rstrip("\n")
        print(playerName + ("'s score was:"), playerScore)
        playerName = inputFile.readline()
    inputFile.close()

def lowestScorer():
    integers = open("golf.dat", "r")
    lowestScore = 0
    for score in integers:
        if lowestScore >= int(score.strip()):
            lowestScore = int(score.strip())
    integers.close()
    print("The lowest score was: ", lowestScore)
```

**I've tried:** I have tried (in vein) to write a function (`lowestScorer`) to extract and display the lowest value, but it didn't occur to me at first, but this is obviously going to fail, based on the way my data is stored.

**Where you can help:** suggest if there is any Pythonic way of adapting my code (rather than re-writing), to allow my program to identify and display the name and scorer of the lowest scorer / integer, saved in my `golf.dat` file?

My suspicion is that I should have written this program with two lists that hold names and scores respective and then written these to golf.dat (for easy extraction and analysis) or created these two lists (as sublists, thus holding names and integer score values separately) but gone a step further and saved them within a master list.

Comment: Some sample input pls

Comment: >>>How many player to score: 2
>>>Please enter player 1's name: John
>>>Please enter player 1's score: 10
>>>Please enter player 2's name: Henry
>>>Please enter player 2's score: 6
>>>John's score was: 10
>>>Henry's score was: 6

Comment: Have you considered loading the file once, at startup, and writing it once, at the end of the program, and to use a dictionary to hold the name:score mapping in the meantime? What you want to do is certainly possible, but reading your file every time just to look up a score seems clunky.

Comment: Also, FYI, you probably got a downvote because there's no example of your `golf.dat` file and the failed code for `lowestScorer` is missing.

Comment: @timgeb - thanks for the tip. Yup, a dictionary would have probably been a better shout; in addition to the suggestions on why I'm down voted (thanks for this), I should have mentioned I'm a rookie and dictionaries isn't something I've covered yet (I'm teaching myself), but I need to.